# How to convert T object to Amazon DynamoDB Document dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, amazon-web-services

I am trying to use DynamoDB in Amazon AWS in my MVC .net project. And I am also trying to do a Business-DataAccess-Model layered project.

I have a GenericDataRepository class which implements an Add() functionality.

I am sending a T object to Add() and I would like to convert that to Amazon's Document object, dynamically. How can I do that and what is the best practice?

```
public void Add(T entity)
{
    if (entity == null)
        return;

    var doc = new Document();

    // Convert entity to Document automatically
    doc["Title"] = entity.Title;
    doc["Body"] = entity.Body;
    doc["Author"] = entity.Author;
    // Convert entity to Document automatically


    .....
    .....       
    .....
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use reflection, for dynamically fill a document:

```
public void Add(T entity)
{
  if (entity == null) 
    return;

  var doc = new Document();
  entity.GetType().GetProperties().ToList().ForEach(x => doc[x.Name] = x.GetValue(entity));
  ...
}
```

Comment: All fields in the class must be property and not executed if have class inside class, in this case, use Document.FromJson(MyToJson(class1))

Answer (score 12):

In a Latest version of aws dynamo db SDK. this feature is supported, you can achieve your goal without any hassle. Simple and Fast

```
    public Document Add <T>(T entity, IAmazonDynamoDB dbClient)
            {
                Amazon.DynamoDBv2.DataModel.DynamoDBContext db = new Amazon.DynamoDBv2.DataModel.DynamoDBContext(dbClient);                                   
                Document document = db.ToDocument(entity);
                return document;
            }
```

Comment: is there a way to map class property and column name, if both are different?

Comment: W/O hassle? No. It need constructor and property setters. Plus no option so customize naming like JSON conversion allows.

Answer (score 7):

I think you can use Json.net to serialize your object to json and then create dynamoDb document form it according to their docs:

```
var jsonText = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(entity, Formatting.Indented);
var item = Document.FromJson(jsonText);
```

Comment: Yes, but pure manual reflection can be complex as objects can be with sub objects, collections etc.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to add the [Serializable] attribute to your T object.